# Highlights code from javascript

Tags: javascript, html, xml, syntax-highlighting

I use SyntaxHighlighter - http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/download/
How i can highlight code from javascript? 
I try

```
var pre = document.createElement("pre");
pre.id = "preXml";
pre.setAttribute("class", "brush: xml");
pre.innerText = myXmlAsString;
```

but code look just like text without color

Comment: can you share a snippet of code?

Comment: Well you do not initialize the it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [installation instructions](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/manual/installation.html), you need to include the core JS, the brush JS, the core CSS and a theme.

You can add the `pre` element in JavaScript as you were doing, but make sure you append the child to an already existing element on the page, in this case `body.

You then need to call `SyntaxHighlighter.all()` to execute the formatting.

```js
var xml = "<div>Test</div>";

var pre = document.createElement("pre");
pre.id = "preXml";
pre.setAttribute("class", "brush: xml");
pre.innerText = xml;
document.body.appendChild(pre);
SyntaxHighlighter.all()
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/SyntaxHighlighter/3.0.83/styles/shCoreDefault.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/SyntaxHighlighter/3.0.83/scripts/shCore.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/SyntaxHighlighter/3.0.83/scripts/shBrushXml.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: If i use innerHTML browser ignore tags, i want see them.
If i use innerText text isn't colored, but if i just make tag <pre class="brush: xml> mycode</pre> its fine, but i need  do it from js

Comment: @karpengold Yes, just noticed the `innerHTML` issue. It highlights fine with the updated code.